# Prove the Identity $\dfrac{\tan\theta}{\cos\theta-\sec\theta} = -\csc\theta$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Been trying this question for over an hour and would like to know how it's done. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \frac{\tan x}{\cos x-\sec x} = \frac{\tan x}{\cos(x)-\frac{1}{\cos(x)}} = \frac{\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}}{\cos(x)-\frac{1}{\cos(x)}} \\[10pt]
= {} &\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)-1}=\frac{\sin(x)}{-\sin^2(x)}=-\frac{1}{\sin(x)}=-\csc(x).
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

$$ \frac{\tan(x)}{\cos(x)-\sec(x)}=\frac{1}{\cos(x)-\frac{1}{\cos(x)}}\cdot \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{\cos(x)}{-(1-\cos^2(x))} \cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=-\csc(x)$$

Comment: Though it is not the question to be answered but still  +1 by me

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Wait what do you mean when you say "thought it is not the question to be answered" kinda confused by that.. also thanks! :)

Comment: I said so because someone downvoted it and I know that it must be someone who thought that it is not a question to be answered, usually highly reputated guys on MSE get irritated from such posts and answers on them. But I m not highly reputated that is why I voted for you.

Comment: Not a post to be answered mean too easy and need no response.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF Ah I see. I like answering these questions since I used to be in the same spot before so I like passing on this knowledge. Thanks for the suggestion anyway - will keep that in mind next time. :)

Comment: I too like answering these questions for the same reason, but when I was typing, I saw your answer flashing and then I did not wanted to put up a duplicate effort.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
& \frac{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}{\cos\theta - \frac{1}{\cos\theta}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}{\frac{\cos^2\theta - 1}{\cos\theta}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}{\frac{-(1 - \cos^2\theta)}{\cos\theta}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}{\frac{-(\sin^2\theta)}{\cos\theta}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} \cdot \frac{\cos\theta}{-\sin^2\theta} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{-1}{\sin\theta} \\[10pt]
= {} & - \csc\theta
\end{align}